# how to set ArrayList from another ArrayList which has elements as Arraylist

Tags: java, jsp, collections, arraylist

iam unable to add to ArrayList which is an atrribute in Form . from ArrayList which has elements as ArrayList.
I have to do the above, to iterate the ArrayList , to display in jsp.

Edit : below is the code in DAO where iam adding ArrayList in to ArrayList

```
while( rs.next())
        {
            if(null!=columnList && columnList.size()>0){
                baseColumnList.add(columnList);
            }
            columnList = new ArrayList();
            for(int i=1; i<=rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); ){

            columnList.add(rs.getString(rs.getMetaData().getColumnLabel(i)));

                //child = new ArrayList();
                i++;
            }
        }
```

In Action class, i have get the each element of parent ArrayList, which is again an ArrayList. add it to form ArrayList

Comment: Please post a little code to show what you mean.

Comment: reason behind downvoting please

Comment: 1) To say "*set ArrayList from another ArrayList*" doesn't make sense. 2) What do you mean by "*which has elements as Arraylist*"? Do you mean that the ArrayList contains ArrayLists? 3) What do you mean by "*which is an attribute in Form*"? Is Form a class? An instance? 4) "*I have to do the above...*", do what? 5) "*to iterate the ArrayList*", where did iteration come into the picture? 6) "*To display in jsp*", where did jsp come into the picture?!

Answer (score 1):

I don't exactly know what you mean but, if I understand correctly, I think you want to loop over an `ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>`?

In that case, you can just loop over each `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>()
..
for (ArrayList<Object> l1 : listOfLists) {
    for (Object something : l1) {
        ..
    }
}
```